Input capacitor of DC-DC convertor-BUCK-TPS548A28RWWR
I'm working on the following reference design from trenz electronic:

4 V to 16 V down to 0.85 V with a maximum output current of 14.2 A


Then I checked the datasheet of the controller TPS548A28RWWR:

4 V to 16 V down to 2.5 V with a maximum output current of 15 A.


I noticed in the datasheet the design (second design) uses three 1µF capacitors in parallel, while the reference design (first design) employs two 1µF capacitors and one 100nF (50V) capacitor. Could you please explain the advantage of substituting a 1µF capacitor with a 100nF capacitor at the input?

The 100nF capacitor may be available in a smaller package size which would have a lower inductance. If you cannot get it in a smaller package then you should use the 1uF size.

Are you sure the max input voltage for the Trenz ref design is 16V? I see 10V-rated input capacitors. Also, please put links to the respective documents i.e. Trenz Elec ref design and the IC datasheet.

You're ignoring the additional 2.2 μF capacitor on the first design.  It's less of a substitute and more of an additional capacitor, and this 2.2 μF is more the substitute.

Smaller caps are better at bypassing higher-frequency transients. Having a range of capacitance values that includes both larger and smaller caps helps give your design greater electrical margins.

Don't read into it too deeply.
Small changes in capacitor selection and rating tend to be a dubious matter, bordering on superstition.
There does exist an objective, rational method we can apply: PDN (Power Distribution Network) analysis.  To summarize: we can construct a model of the PCB layout (whether hand-waved from a simple enough layout that can be analyzed by inspection, or extracted numerically as an equivalent model with use of an entire E&M field solver), apply components to it in various locations, and of values, and see what gives the best results given various decision criteria.
Examples of criteria might be: input/output filtering; common-mode noise; supply impedance at an IC's power port(s); noise transmitted across the board; etc.  Since ceramic capacitors and ferrite beads are nonlinear, criteria may include nonlinear models under bias (voltage and current, at nominal values, peak startup/load/fault conditions, etc.), temperature sweep, and so on.  There might be knock-on effects like EMC, or signal quality (usually not so much gross digital signal integrity, but subtler effects like jitter, clock purity, spurious tones, etc.).
The general reason we choose capacitors for bypass, is because they have low impedance at high frequencies, and high at DC (so they don't dissipate DC power).  The general reason we recommend tight, compact layouts, is to minimize stray inductance between components -- inductance causes impedance to rise at the highest frequencies, which, gone high enough, will eventually violate the supply impedance requirements of some device, and malfunction or damage will result.  Generally speaking, inductance rises proportionally with distance, so we want the physical size/outline of a circuit to be small if possible.  (And failing that, we can drive down the geometric factor that's multiplied by the inductance/length rate: using wider traces, and thinner height above plane.)
Capacitors cannot simply be thrown in at random.  The stray inductance of the component's body itself, let alone connecting traces, vias, etc., create a resonant circuit around the capacitor.  Capacitors can resonate with and against each other, contributing peaks and valleys to the self-impedance spectrum, or peaks in the transfer spectrum.
Or, well.. I mean, they can be [thrown in at random], but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.  One can get lucky, and apply superstitious ideas (like using a geometric series of capacitors in parallel for bypass), and manage not to encounter problems (perhaps the resulting impedance peaks are still below the device limit, or perhaps other reasons save the design, like accidentally beneficial via placement), or perhaps one does in fact encounter problems (e.g. clock jitter is increased above nominal limits) but doesn't realize it anyway (the receiver's jitter tolerance is wider, etc.).  Or a data-dependent error results, and a given (say embedded) system just never happens to process that pattern, and never trips the latent problem.  Or maybe it's an EMI problem, but an alternative solution is used (ferrite beads on cables, more filtering elsewhere than the offending source, shielding placed over the board, etc.)
As you may gather, producing an accurate model of the board is a nontrivial task, either because one need be highly skilled to produce an accurate assessment (such workers are rare, and generally highly paid), or esoteric tools are required (PCB-level field simulators), or because developing and testing the model at all, simply takes a lot more time than a given project can afford.
Engineering is ultimately the science of compromise.  We cannot analyze every aspect of every system we design.  Many aspects must be left to assumptions, of varying quality from engineer to engineer.  Repeating bypass capacitors might prove an effective strategy.  Using tapered values or body sizes may be effective.  Both strategies, and others, might be effective in a given design (a low-voltage power converter such as this for example), and ineffective, or outright wrong, in others.  Until one has encountered those examples, and tested them, one does not truly know how well the strategy works.
And even then, one only really knows that a strategy works (to some degree of "work") in any given scenario; it's even harder to infer the sensitivities, how much of the scenario can be changed (say, voltage, current or frequency of a converter; layout lengths, layers, aspect ratios; component size and placement; etc.).
Realize that, a dozen different engineers can develop these biases, independently, and all think that their preferred strategy is far more general than it really is -- that is, that all their strategies share some degree of overlap, whereas rationally we should expect only very few strategies (perhaps only one) are objectively best.  This happens, because they've never tested it, or don't have the (theoretical) tools to understand the nuances that differentiate their strategies.
